# Mapping out a categories model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

What's the best way to create a 'category' model? For example, I have a product that can have multiple categories like 'furniture', 'futuristic' and 'modern'. Should I have a separate Categories model? It could say the type of item and what product it belongs to? That just seems so heavy for such a small use. I'm unsure of the best way to do this. Any ideas?

I was thinking about doing this:

```
  create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "category"                                  null: false
    t.integer  "product_id",                               null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: Are you asking whether you need multiple `categories` table for each `furniture`, `futuristic` and `modern` ? If thats your question, then you just need one `product` table and one `category` table. Its good way to normalize the data.

Comment: I'm asking if I need one 'category: futuristic product_id 12  then category:futuristic product_id 11 then category modern product_id 11'

Comment: yes this is good approach. Its good to go.